# How to find the total number of handshakes if there are $n$ married couples at a party and each person shakes hand with everyone except their spouse

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

There are $n$ married couples at a party. Each person shakes hand with every person other than her or his spouse. Find the total number of handshakes.

My method was Total person $=2n$.  $1$ person can make handshakes with $2n-2$ people, and there are $2n$ people in the room. Total handshakes $= 2n(2n-2)$. But this answer contains repetition. As every handshake is considered twice. So we divide by $2$ to get our answer Answer $= n(n-1 )$. But the given answer is $2n(n-1)$. How???

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ shake hands, that is one handshake, not two.

Comment: If you divide the $(2n-2)$ portion of your initial computation by $2$, you immediately get the answer $2n(n-1)$

Comment: You divided by $4$ instead of $2$. Otherwise the reasoning is correct.

Comment: Okay that's embarassing .. anyways thanks alot for helping

Answer (score 3):

Your reasoning is fine, you just made a mistake in algebra in the final step. Note that $\frac{(2n)(2n-2)}{2}$ can be rewritten as $\left( \frac{2n}{2} \right)\cdot \left( \frac{2n-2}{1} \right)$ **or** $\left( \frac{2n}{1} \right) \cdot \left( \frac{2n-2}{2} \right)$, but if you divide both factors by $2$ you've actually divided the expression by $4$.

Comment: Thanks man .. got it ...

Answer (score 2):

Break the problem into three parts. First we'll calculate **Male Male handshakes** Since there are $n$ males so the total number of handshakes should be $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ Similarly **Female Female handshakes** are also
$\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ So **total number of same gender handshakes** are $n(n-1)$

---

Now calculate **total number of different gender handshakes**

Each Male will shake hand with $n-1$ females (excluding his spouse) and there are total $n$ males So **total number of different gender handshakes** should be $n(n-1)$

---

Total handshakes altogether are $n(n-1)+n(n-1)=2n(n-1)$

Answer (score 2):

There $2n$ people, so the total number of handshakes, including between spouses, would be be $\frac{2n(2n-1)}{2}$ and, because there are $n$ couples we must subtract $n$ "wrongly" counted handshakes.
So we have
$\begin{align}  
\frac{2n(2n-1)}{2}-n&=n(2n-1)-n\\
&=n^2-2n\\ 
&=n(2n-2)\\ 
&=2n(n-1)
\end{align}$.